# Git Remote Deploy on Windows Server

Tags: git, windows-server-2016

I have an Windows 2016 Server and i want to develop on my local PC and push changes with git to the server for deployment.
I have set up openssh and can log into the server and access directories.
Afterwards i installed git for windows.
Let's say my repository is in `C:\repo\tool`. SSH defaults me to `C:\users\foo`
In `C:\Users\foo` is a link created with

```
symlink \J C:\Users\foo\repo C:\repo\
```

I initialized a repo with git init in `C:\repo\tool`.
On my local machine i initialized an empty git repo, added some files and want to commit them now to the server
I tried on my local machine

```
git remote add deploy ssh:\\foo@server.com\repo\tool
git push deploy
```

I can authenticate to the machine, but git answers me with

```
fatal: ''/repo/tool'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

Folder and files have full rights for the user used in ssh connection.
How do i set the ssh url right?

Comment: Git is not suitable for deployment. When you push, the server’s working directory will not be updated automatically.

Comment: I tried to follow this guide for deployment https://medium.com/@francoisromain/vps-deploy-with-git-fea605f1303b it seems it suits my needs